# How can you display the progress of a given task (such as transcoding), when you're using a background worker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm making an application to transcode videos from one format to another using Streamio FFMPEG. I'd like to display the progress percentage to the user, but I'm doing the transcoding in a background task (using sidekiq and redis) as the transcoding can take considerable time to finish.

I'm unfamiliar with what could be the ideal way to display the progress in the browser. In the case of Streamio, it provides a way to display its progress, like this:

```
movie.transcode("movie.mp4") { |progress| puts progress } # 0.2 ... 0.5 ... 1.0
```

How can I save the value of `progress` to something that can be later retrieved to be used in the browser? Do I have to save it to a variable? To a file? To the database? As I said, I'm unfamiliar with what could be the best practice for this. Saving it to a database sounds like it'd create too much overhead, and I'm unsure what variable could hold this information for the period it takes to complete the transcoding.

For the sake of simplicity let's just say this could be printed in a simple `<p>` tag when a certain page is visited. I'll do something more complex later via Javascript (using Vue or React) to print the progress as it changes, but for now I'd just like to know how could this be retrieved at all.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**:

With the help of jdno I managed to get this to work.

First, the sidekiq-status installation. They mention you must add it to the sidekiq middleware, which previous to this, I had no idea it "existed". So, to add it to the middleware you create this file:

```
# config/initializers/sidekiq.rb

require 'sidekiq'
require 'sidekiq-status'

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  # accepts :expiration (optional)
  Sidekiq::Status.configure_client_middleware config, expiration: 30.minutes
end

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  # accepts :expiration (optional)
  Sidekiq::Status.configure_server_middleware config, expiration: 30.minutes

  # accepts :expiration (optional)
  Sidekiq::Status.configure_client_middleware config, expiration: 30.minutes
end
```

Then, the worker I use to transcode the files looks like this:

```
# app/workers/convert_tomp4.rb

class ConvertTomp4
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include Sidekiq::Status::Worker

  sidekiq_options retry: false

  def perform(original_file, attachment_id)
    destination_file="tmp/#{Digest::MD5.hexdigest(DateTime.now.to_s)}.mp4"
    puts "Transcoding #{original_file} into #{destination_file}"
    transcoding_options = %w(-f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -acodec aac -b:v 2M -b:a 128k -strict -2)
    total 100
    at 0    
    movie=FFMPEG::Movie.new(original_file).transcode(destination_file,transcoding_options) { |p| at p*100 }
    attachment=Attachment.find(attachment_id)
    attachment.tomp4=File.open(destination_file)
    attachment.processing=false
    attachment.save
  end

end
```

`Attachment` is the model I'm using to save the files, while `tomp4` is the field that saved the file information to Carrierwave. `processing` is a field I'm using to know whether the worker process is active, which is merely redundant, but I wanted to save it to the main db.

Notice that I'm using `{|p| at p*100}` to track the progress. Normally, `p` would have values between 0.0 to 1.0, so I'm multiplying it by 100 to know the percentage. The variable `at` is an inbuilt variable from sidekiq-status, just as `total`.

Finally, to get the values in a view or anywhere else in the application, I use:

```
Sidekiq::Status::at @attachment.jobid
```

`jobid` is assigned just before I send the task to the queue. The following is part of what I use in my Carrierwave uploader:

```
# app/uploaders/attachment_uploader.rb

def convert_to_mp4(arg1)
  if file.path
    if file.extension == 'mov'
      original = "#{root}/#{self.model.original.url}"
      job_id = ConvertTomp4.perform_async(original,self.model.id)
      Rails.logger.debug "Job ID: #{job_id}"
      self.model.jobid = job_id
      self.model.processing = true
      self.model.save
      Rails.logger.debug "Sending transcoding to the queue. #{original} with ID: #{job_id}"
    end
  end
end
```

Excuse the many debugger lines.

`original` is the field I'm using to save the original file. As of currently I do not know how to keep a single version of the uploaded files, so I made a 2nd uploader to handle the converted files, and they're saved to `tomp4`.

Answer (score 2):

We use [sidekiq-status](https://github.com/utgarda/sidekiq-status) for this. It stores the progress in Redis, thus avoiding expansive database operations.

How you want to expose the information to the client depends a little bit on your needs. For us, the progress updates so slowly that we just poll it using Javascript every few seconds. We have a model that represents a task, e.g. `FileConversion` with attributes like `file_path` and `size`, and then we expose the status of a job through `FileConversionController`.

For our use case, this has been a pretty good solution that requires very little effort on your end.

Comment: Interesting, it looks promising. I'll take a look.

Comment: I'm checking the installation of the gem, and adding something to the middleware chain is a little over my head. Is there an example I can see of this?